# View does not react to anything after orientation change

Tags: java, android

I have a button for sending data to server. I want this button to be visible only when there are some data to send, so I have a listener which succesfully triggers every time there is something to send. Everything works fine, until i change device ortientation (landscape to portrait, doesn't matter in which position it starts). Attributtes set by XML works, I'm just not able to change them programmatically.

I've tried checking id, it is still the same.

EDIT:
My code:

```
Jidelnicek.ObjednavkyListener objednavkyListener = new Jidelnicek.ObjednavkyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onObjednavka(boolean jeObjednavka) {
                if (jeObjednavka && (btnOdeslat.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)) {
                    btnOdeslat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else if (!jeObjednavka) {
                    btnOdeslat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        };
```

`jidelnicek.setObjednavkaListener(objednavkyListener);`

Comment: share the activity code where you place the listener

Comment: in which life cycle method you have placed the jidelnicek.setObjednavkaListener(objednavkyListener);

Comment: @ShubhamJain in onResume

Comment: @ShubhamJain I've solved it. I checked if jidelnicek has any listener, and if it did not, I've set new listener on it. I've removed the condition and now it sets new listener every time. This resolved the issue. Thanks for your time anyway and sorry I've wasted it like this

Comment: no issue we are here to help each other